# How to disable a JqueryUI dialog Button from ASP.NET Code Behind?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am doing a project and I need to disable a jquery ui dialog button from code behind. My code is :

```
var viewPopup = $('#popupPanel').dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 580,
            width: 800,
            appendTo: $('form:first'),
            buttons: [{
                id:"jqueryBtn",
                text: "Submit",
                click: function () {
                    $("#<%=aspnetBtn.ClientID%>").click();
                }
            }]
        });
```

I need to disable jqueryBtn from code behind. I know it is a client-server issue. How can I do that?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: i don't understand `disable jqueryBtn from code behind` , it means when the dialog is opened and then disabled jqueryBtn?

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusions. There is a dialog button called jqueryBtn, and I want to disable it when the dialog opens. Because it is not a ASP.NET button so I dont know how to do that. Because for asp.net button, we can use the button id and set the enable = false, but it is not working for dialog button.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `asp:HiddenField` as a flag. Set the flag on code-behind. After the code runs there will be a postback and after that DOMReady. In DOMReady check the flag and disable / enable the button.

Comment: Hi thanks! I am also thinking about using hidden field way. I will explore more about clientscript way later. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: the script way wont work in theory. haven't tested it `DOMReady` which negates everythingelse

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you want to achieve
but if you want to disable a button in server side, there are a few options：

1. make the button an asp.net server control like using  tag, then put the logic in code behind
2. have an disable button function in client side, then call that function in server side by using ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock

Comment: Hey thanks dude. I am exploring more about the script way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jquery dialog event open](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open)

```
var viewPopup = $('#popupPanel').dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 580,
        width: 800,
        appendTo: $('form:first'),
        buttons: [{
            id:"jqueryBtn",
            text: "Submit",
            click: function () {
                $("#<%=aspnetBtn.ClientID%>").click();
            }
        }],
        open: function() {
           $('#jqueryBtn').button("disable");
        }
   });
```

and this is a **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6xedvsym/16/)**